# Blazor Radzen dropdown on primitive type?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a Blazor application where I am using the Radzen components. Specifically, I am using the drop down component. I am running into an issue where I am unable to bind the Data to a list of floats.

```
<RadzenDropDown @bind-Value="@model.modelValue" Data="options"></RadzenDropDown>

@code {
    List<float> options;
    options.Add(1);
    options.Add(2);
    ...
}
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

I know it is possible to do the following to make it work:

```
<RadzenDropDown @bind-Value="@model.modelValue" TextProperty="Text"  Data="@(options.Select(s => new { Text = s, Value = s }))"></RadzenDropDown>
```

I'd like to avoid that because I have an modal that allows the user to manually enter a value and I can't get that value to show if I have to convert my float value to an object.

Is there anyway to bind to primitives?

Comment: Since the error suggests it expects an `IEnumerable` perhaps you can coerce it,e.g.
`IEnumerable<float> options = new List<float>() { 1, 2 };` ? Though I suspect it is more that the binding model does not really support floats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component is looking for an `IEnumerable<object>`, not `float`. You can pass in a `List<object>` (since it implements `IEnumerable`), and  then put `float`s in it, since `float`'s are `object`s. Here's a full working example.

```
@page "/radzentest"


<RadzenDropDown TValue="float" Data="Options"></RadzenDropDown>

@code {

    List<object> Options = new List<object>();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Options.Add(1.1f);
        Options.Add(2.5f);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

I'm not sure if there is a technical reason why Radzen couldn't do it that I don't understand, but it seems like a miss on their part to not have it be `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<object>`